# Align position of a table exactly to another one

Tags: tables, floats, horizontal-alignment, positioning, captions

I have a problem. I just made a table which was very wide, so I decided to split it into two smaller ones. Turned out the 2nd half is a little bit smaller in width than the first one.
Now I want these **two tables to be below each other, meaning with the exact same distance from the left.** Also the bigger of these is centered, but I don't want the 2nd and smaller one to be centered as well. I want it to be starting from the left at the same position as the bigger one. How can you do this in Latex?
Here is the code of the two tables:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
\setcapindent{0em}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb]
\begin{floatrow}
\ttabbox{
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE &
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE & 
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
} 
{
\caption{ABCDE table}\label{tab:ABCDE}
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htpb]
\begin{floatrow}
\ttabbox{
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE &   \\
ABCDE &
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE &  \\
ABCDE & 
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
} 
{
\caption{ABCDE table}\label{tab:ABCDE}
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Thank you for any hints :)

Comment: Have you tried using the `tabulary` package?

Comment: Please always post a complete document, it makes it much easier to test any answer. Your example is not at all clear as it only has one table. In particular why two tabular why can't you just add the second half below the first, then alignment is automatic.

Comment: @TomM, what David was talking about is called a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  Yoy can also check the [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package in CTAN.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done
The thing is a package would be ok for my purpose, but to really understand Latex it shouldnt be to hard to write your own command to align the second table to the same from-the-left postion as the right one, or not?

Comment: @MarioS.E. I know what it is ;) I edited the question to include a complete example

Comment: but why two tables environments rather than one? as such it isn't even guaranteed that they be on the same page so vertical alignment is not well defined. The natural way to make sure they are the same distance from the left is to left align, indented by a fixed amount, or as I ask above to make it just one tabular. If they are separately floating tables with their own caption floatrow and ttabbox seem inappropriate for siingle tabular (you could customise teh caption using caption package)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why you want to use `floatrow`. However, here's a possibility: measure the first table and set the second one in a minipage as wide.
The usage of `geometry` is just for drawing a frame around the page to see the placement with respect to the margins.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just for this example
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\newbox{\firsttabbox}

\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
\setcapindent{0em}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb]
\sbox{\firsttabbox}{\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\begin{floatrow}
\ttabbox
  {\usebox{\firsttabbox}}
  {\caption{ABCDE table}\label{tab:ABCDE}}
\end{floatrow}

\bigskip

\begin{floatrow}
\ttabbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\wd\firsttabbox}
  \raggedright
  \begin{tabular}{lccc}
  \toprule
  ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
  ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
  ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}}
  {\caption{ABCDE table}\label{tab:ABCD}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

When you have set the save box with `\sbox{\firsttabbox}`, its width is available as `\wd\firsttabbox`. So we can feed this width to the following `minipage` and “use” the saved box in the first `floatrow`.

Pay attention that your usage

```
\tabbox{
  <material>
}
{
 \caption{...}
}
```

adds spaces which should be protected with `%` or with other tokens. So if for instance you want the second `\tabbox` with “isolated” braces, you must do

```
\ttabbox{% <-- important
  \begin{minipage}{\wd\firsttabbox}
  \raggedright
  \begin{tabular}{lccc}
  \toprule
  ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
  ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
  ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}% <-- important
}
{% <-- important
 \caption{ABCDE table}\label{tab:ABCD}% <-- important
}
```

A `%` after `\end{tabular}` is not needed, because `\end{minipage}` gets rid of that space.

---

A solution without `floatrow`; we first typeset the tables for knowing their width and then do the final typesetting.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just for this example
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{environ}

\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
\setcapindent{0em}
\pagestyle{headings}

\NewEnviron{lefttables}[1][tp]{%
  \global\tabwidth=0pt
  \vbox{
    \renewcommand\caption[2][]{}%
    \renewcommand\label[1]{}%
    \let\latextabular\tabular
    \let\latexendtabular\endtabular
    \def\tabular{\setbox8=\hbox\bgroup\latextabular}%
    \def\endtabular{\latexendtabular\egroup\settabwidth}
    \BODY
  }
  \begin{table}[#1]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{\tabwidth}\raggedright
  \BODY
  \end{minipage}
  \end{table}
}
\newdimen\tabwidth
\newcommand{\settabwidth}{%
  \ifdim\wd8>\tabwidth \global\tabwidth=\wd8 \fi
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lefttables}[htpb]
\caption{ABCDE table}\label{tab:ABCDE}

\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{lefttables}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you that seems to do it. I will try to understand all the commands you have used. I am using floatrow to get the type of captioning where you have the table nr first and in the next line the description. It doesn't work in scrreprt otherwise

Comment: @TomM I've added some explanations and simplified the code (I was using a slightly different approach and forgot to remove the unneeded part).

Comment: alright thank you. Now I understand your approach

Comment: @egreg I am just back to this example, and I decided not to use floatrow. Can you provide a solution for the same MWE, but without floatrow, ie just using table/tabular environments? I tried it, but I get too many errors to figure it out.

Comment: @TomM And do you want the caption aligned with the left edge of the table?

Comment: @egreg I am thinking about not adding another caption instead (to generate one whole table), but the second part of the table should still start from the left where the first one does

Comment: @TomM Note that the last solution doesn't assume that the first table is the widest one.

Comment: @egreg yep I see. You also updated your solution. Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false,]{caption}    
\setcapindent{0em}
\parindent=0pt
\newsavebox\TBox
\begin{document}

\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}% only demo

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\savebox\TBox{%  save it to get the width of the table
    \begin{tabular}{lccccc}\toprule
    ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
    ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
    ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}

\parbox{\wd\TBox}{%   caption and table 1 in a \parbox
\caption{ABCDE table}\label{tab:ABCDE}
\usebox\TBox}

\bigskip
\parbox{\wd\TBox}{%   caption and table 2 with width of 1
\caption{ABCDE table}\label{tab:ABCD}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}\toprule
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE   \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE   \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE   \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh just two consecutive tabulars. Thank you! But if I try `\centering`, both tables are centered, which looks bad in case of these tables. The first one should be centered and the second one should start from the left where the first one did.

Comment: @TomM: see my edited answer

Comment: What's the purpose of `varwidth`?

Comment: @egreg: no purpose ... was from another example

Comment: Note that I cannot accept any answers here, because that was asked from a different account at a different location. I will try to do this later if I get back. But might take a while :)

Comment: @TomM You can merge your accounts by doing as described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts